# Javascript - How to silently retrieve the source of a webpage that won't respond to fetch() request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, fetch-api

I have a Firefox/Chrome web extension. When the user clicks the extension's button, the extension should retrieve the text of a dynamically generated URL. Because I am writing a web extension, I have no control over this URL.

Here's an example of what **should** (but doesn't) happen:

1) User clicks my extension's button

2) The extension generates the following URL - this URL will change each time the extension's button is clicked:

Example URL:

https://smmry.com/sm_portal.php?&SM_TOKEN=2635119454&SM_POST_SAVE=0&SM_REDUCTION=-1&SM_CHARACTER=-1&SM_LENGTH=7&SM_URL=http://money.cnn.com/2018/04/03/investing/amazon-stock-widely-held/index.html

3) The extension retrieves the text of the file at that URL and does something with it.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<Insert_Code_That_Generates_URL and assigns it to generatedURL variable>
console.log("Fetching tokenSite");
fetch(generatedURL).then((response) => {
                console.log("Token site fetched");
                console.log(response);
            })
```

However, what actually happens is the following:

[image]

However, I can successfully manually open the URL or use `browser.tabs.create({ url: generatedURL});` to open the URL in a new page.

I suspect the server is preventing the `fetch()` request from working because it is from an extension.

What are ways I can retrieve the text of the file located at that URL?

Someone has suggested loading the URL inside of an iFrame, but I don't know how to do that (especially in the context of a web extension). So an example of that would be helpful.

Sidenote - once the console did not even log "Token site fetched", rather there was just never a response from the XHR request.

Here is my `manifest.json`

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Summarizer",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Summarizes webpages",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "downloads",
        "*://*.smmry.com/*"
    ],

    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "browser_style": true,
        "default_popup": "popup/choose_page.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/summarizer-icon-16.png",
            "32": "icons/summarizer-icon-32.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. is `<Insert_Code_That_Generates_URL and assigns it to generatedURL variable>` literally part of your code? 2. Share your extensions manifest - perhaps you haven't added the right permissions in there

Comment: I shared my extensions manifest. Also the <insert etc..> section is not literally part of my code - it is representing some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` returns a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, not the response content itself, so logging the stream like that won't work - you need to parse the stream first, something like:

```
fetch(generatedURL).then((response) => {
  console.log("Token site responded");
  return response.text();
}).then(responseText => {
  console.log("Token site parsed");
  console.log(responseText);
});
```

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch